# Audio sound clipping issue on IOS devices especially with Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, audio

I have a webpage where am loading lots of sounds and playing them on different animations.

I noticed that on IOS devices sounds were being clipped and not fully played as on desktop. Especially safari has lots of differences from desktop browsers.

Am loading the sounds on click of sound button like the below

The markup

```
<audio id="firstreelstop_sound" src="sounds/wheelStop1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

var firstReelStopsound = document.getElementById('firstreelstop_sound');
jQuery(document).on("click", '.soundIcon', function() {
     firstReelStopsound.load();
     secondReelStopsound.load();
     thirdReelStopsound.load();
     fourthReelStopsound.load();
     fifthReelStopsound.load();
     ...... etc
});
```

And then when i need them i just use .play().

It seems that not all sounds were being loaded.

I also noticed that when i click on something on IOS mobile devices there is a bit of a delay(200-300ms) between clicking and doing the actions which are inside the click.

Any idea how this can be solved?
Thanks.